# VS code bug. css is not grabbing element at all

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, css

Not sure what the deal is, and I can't find an answer anywhere else. But the CSS changes aren't loading in the browser. Even for a simple color change to the h1 tag. However, I went into my other projects to see if this was the case and this worked fine. It seems to be only when I start a new project. I'm using visual studio code as my editor.

(sorry for the odd description, definitly a newbie and still learning the lingo)

Just simply doing this, and the changes won't load in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>

h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Is your code block all one file? You need to put your CSS in `<style>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS declaration

```
h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

may be directly in your `.html` file, but then it must be inside the `<style>` tag, which must be in turn inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<head>
    <style>
        h1 {color: red;}
    </style>
</head>
```

so your full code will be

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        h1 {color:red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try either applying inline css properties to your h1 tag like:

```
<body>
    <h1 style="color:red;">Hello</h1>
</body>
```

Or you can put your code in  tag like:

```
<head>
    <style>
        h1 {color: red;}
    </style>
</head>
```

Or you can use an external css file and link it in your head section.